# Spring MVC pdf generation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, itext

I have a java web application based on Spring MVC. 
The task is to generate a pdf file. As all knows the spring engine has its own built-in iText library so the generating of pdf file is really simple. First of all we need to do is to overload AbstractView and create some PdfView. And the seconf thing is to use that view in controller. But in my application I am also have to be able to store generated pdf files on local drive or give my users some link to download that file. So the view in that case is not suitable for me.

I want to create some universal pdf generator that creates a pdf file and returns the bytes array. So I can use that array for file storing (on hard drive) or printing it directly in browser. And the question is  - are there any way to use such engine (that returns only the bytes array) in PdfVIew solution? I am asking because overloaded buildPdfDocument method (in PdfView) already have PdfWriter and Document parameters.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; you should be able to use a view and save it to a file.

Try using [Flying Saucer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) and its iTextRenderer when you overload AbstractPdfView.

```
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
public class MyAbstractView extends AbstractView {
   OutputStream os;

   public void buildPdfDocument(Map<String,Object> model, com.lowagie.text.Document document, com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   //process model params
   os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
   ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
   String url = "http://www.mysite.com"; //set your sample url namespace here
   renderer.setDocument(document, url); //use the passed in document
   renderer.layout();
   renderer.createPDF(os);
   os.close();
   }
}

protected final void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String,Object> model,
                                         HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response)
                                  throws Exception{
 if(os != null){
  response.outputStream = os;
 }

public byte[] getPDFAsBytes(){
  if(os != null){
     byte[] stuff;
     os.write(stuff);
     return stuff;
  }
}
```

}

You'll probably have to tweak the sample implementation shown here, but that should provide a basic gist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I do not use grails. Does somebody know how to implement it on "pure" java + spring?

Comment: Grails is just Spring MVC and other stuff in Groovy, which is much like Java. This answer is meant as a reference point for you to be able to construct similar functionality by inspecting the library's source, which is available at http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-rendering/trunk/. Download version 0.3 and look specifically at the PdfRenderingService and its parent class, and you'll see it's essentially analogous to pure Java.

Comment: Rendering just uses Flying Saucer under the covers, which has a pretty good tutorial on how you would use it specifically to create an output stream. Check out the link.

Comment: Could you provide some example code how it looks in controller? Especially the part where you store a view in file?

Comment: A controller is just a class with the specific responsibility of mediating between models and views. Consequently, file manipulation in it should work the same way as any other class where you write the contents of a byte array to a file. I'm sure you can Google for examples of file writing. 

Generally, however, this work should be done in an _application service_, not a controller. The controller should delegate to the service (passing the byte array), which handles that operation. The Rendering plugin was chosen because it very cleanly shows how to achieve such nice separation of concerns

Comment: That's the problem that I can't find any mention of generating view programmatically and receiving its content.

Comment: You really can't derive, from the provided code snippets and some general programming knowledge, how to write a controller/service method that: (1) instantiates an object of the MyAbstractView class (2) calls its buildPdfDocument() and getPdfAsBytes() methods and stores the result in an instance variable [this is, in essence, 'generating the view programmatically and receiving its content'], and (3) creates a new FileOutputStream object that you save that data to?

Comment: Thanks, I am still newbie in Spring. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions the link you mentioned is broken, the updated link for your answer is https://xhtmlrenderer.java.net/